# Setting listeners to groups of markers using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-markers, android-maps-v2

I am working on an Android app where the Google Map has markers for different categories of locations. For instance, collection of markers for places to visit near the current location and collection of markers for places visited so far.

I found that all the markers on the map can be set with Listeners using

```
GoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(OnMarkerClickListener)
```

However, I have a collection of Markers

```
ArrayList<Marker> markerList1 
ArrayList<Marker> markerList2
```

and I want to set markers in markerList1 with one Listener and markers in markerList2 with other Listener. Please help me get to the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have two such lists, a direct way would be to do

```
if (markerList1.contains(marker)) {
    doFirstAction(marker);
} else {
    doSecondAction(marker);
}
```

inside onMarkerClick.

However contains is a linear search, so if the amount of markers in a single list is large and you have more than two categories or the amount of categories might change in the future, I suggest switching to a single Map instead, e.g.

```
private Map<Marker, OnMarkerClickListener> allMarkers;

// in onCreate
OnMarkerClickListener firstActionListener = new ...
OnMarkerClickListener secondActionListener = new ...

Marker marker = ...
allMarkers.put(marker, firstActionListener);

// in global onMarkerClickListener
return allMarkers.get(marker).onMarkerClick(marker);
```

This way you have your separate listeners, code is optimal and adheres to the open/closed principle: if you add new category, you don't change existing code.

Answer (score 1):

The method `OnMarkerClickListener` is set for a map object and cannot be set at marker or marker group level. This means the same `public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker)` will be triggered on clicking any marker on the map.

Now to handle the clicks for different types of markers, you need to use an `if else` logic within this function. You can identify to which group a marker belongs by possibly checking for some string match in details like `marker.getTitle() or marker.getSnippet()` or by checking a hashmap or sqlite db entry that contains more details on a marker.